# OpenCV2 и Python - не могу сделать повторный снимок с веб-камеры

Tags: python, opencv, web-камера

Пишу программу, которая получает изображение с web-камеры при выполнении определенного условия. Как только условие выполняется, создается картинка, но в последующем картинки не получаются - размер составляет 0кБ и они не открываются. В чем может быть проблема и как её решить?

```
import cv2
import time
import serial
import numpy as np
import time


ser = serial.Serial('COM6', 9600)
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while(1):
    new_ser = ser.readline().split()
    print(new_ser[5])
    if int(new_ser[5]) >= 9400:
        for i in range(30):
            cap.read()
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        filename1 = time.strftime('%Y%m%d-%H%M%S')
        cv2.imwrite(filename1 + '.png', frame)
        cap.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: попробуйте вынести за пределы цикла `cap.release(); cv2.destroyAllWindows()`

Comment: @MaxU Да, помогло. Спасибо большое!